# bracketsでjqueryによるbgSwitcherプラグインを使用したいのですが、うまく適用できません

Tags: html, jquery, css, adobe-brackets

表題の件について、モニターの最上部にてフルスクリーンでの複数画像のスライドを行いたいのですが、
jsの読み込みが原因なのか、複数画像の相対パスの表示方法が違うのか、うまくできない状況です。

以下に、うまく表示されない原因ではないかと思われる箇所を3点表記しました。

---

1. js読み込みとして、htmlのheadに`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`を入力し、
   /body 直前に`<script src="js/script.js"></script>`を入力しました。
2. 「jQuery.BgSwitcher」をダウンロードし、jquery.bgswitcher.jsファイルを
   htmlの /body 直前に`<script src="js/jquery.bgswitcher.js"></script>`として表記しました。
3. jsコードの背景画像に記入した表示させたい画像の相対パスについて、
   images: ['img/bg1.jpg','img/bg2.jpg','img/bg3.jpg'],と参考にしたサイトに記載のダミー画像をcssのbackground-imageでの相対パスでの表示のように、
   images: ['../images/index/img01.jpg','../images/index/img02.jpg','../images/index/img03.jpg']に変更しましたが、モニターでうまく表示がされません。

---

下部にhtml, css, jqueryそれぞれのコードを添付いたしました。

jsの読み込みを変更させたり、色々と試してみたのですが、モニターで画像の表示が確認できません。
jsなどのコードの書き方は、学習サービスの「プロゲート」を参考にして書いております。

大変お手数ですが、解決策を教えていただける方がいらっしゃいましたら
よろしくお願いいたします。

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>タイトルタイトルタイトル</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ress/dist/ress.min.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@400;700&family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg-slider">
            <h1 class="bg-slider__title">BGSWITCHER DEMO PAGE</h1>
        </div>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.bgswitcher.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
    width: 1170px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg-slider {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.bg-slider__title{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

js

```
$(function(){
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.bgswitcher.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
        $('.bg-slider').bgSwitcher({
            images: ['../images/index/img01.jpg','../images/index/img02.jpg','../images/index/img03.jpg'], // 背景画像
        });
    });
    </script>
});
```

Comment: 現象が再現できるソースを記述していただくことは可能ですか？[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を参考に作成してみてください

Comment: ソースを記述いたしましたので、ご確認いただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問追記していただいた「js」以下のソースコードはHTML中の「js/script.js」の中身ということですか？

Comment: その通りです。「js」はhtmlの「js/script.js」の内容としました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そもそものJavascriptの記述の仕方に勘違いをされているようです。
外部リソースとしてJavascriptを呼び出す場合はscriptタグは必要ないです。
そのままJavascriptを記述してください

```
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.bg-slider').bgSwitcher({
            images: ['../images/index/img01.jpg','../images/index/img02.jpg','../images/index/img03.jpg'], // 背景画像
        });
    });
```

またその記述の仕方ですと以下のようにJavascriptのエラーが発生するはずです。

```js
$(function(){
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.bgswitcher.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
        $('.bg-slider').bgSwitcher({
            images: ['../images/index/img01.jpg','../images/index/img02.jpg','../images/index/img03.jpg'], // 背景画像
        });
    });
    </script>
});
```

もっともシンプルな確認の仕方はブラウザでF12でコンソールを開いて確認できます。
そのほかの方法もいろいろなサイトで紹介されています。
まずはJavascirptのデバック方法を学んでもらってエラーがない状態になるようになることを目指しましょう。

Comment: keitaro_so　様

Comment: keitaro_so　様
ご回答いただき、誠にありがとうございます。

jqueryコードをscriptタグなしで記入したのですが、
ブラウザ表示させた際、背景画像が表示されない状況です。
index.htmlと同じ階層にcssフォルダとjsフォルダ、imagesフォルダがあり、
imagesフォルダの一階層下にindexフォルダ、その一つ下の階層に
●○○.jpgになっているのですが、上の背景画像のコードでなぜ表示させることができないのかがわからない状況です。

背景画像の表示方法がお分かりでいらっしゃいましたら、
教えていただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Index.htmlと同列にimagesがあるならダブルドットではなくシングルドットでは？「相対URL」で検索して書き方を学んでください

Comment: シングルドットも無くして、images/から始めるとうまく表示されました。
この度は誠にありがとうございました。

Comment: それは良かったです。また回答で解決された場合はこちらを参考にしてください。「[回答がついたら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)」ありがとうというコメントは不要です。